# How can I search for a file with fixed name length using ls?

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards

In a directory, I have files like

```
lazer_100506
lazer_100707
lazer_091211
lazer_110103
lazer_100406_temp
lazer_100622#delete
```

etc

How can I get a listing of only the first four files?

```
$ ls lazer_......
ls: lazer_......: No such file or directory
$
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple methods:

#### `ls` only

```
ls lazer_??????
```

#### `ls` and `egrep`

```
ls | egrep '^lazer_.{6}$'
```

#### `find`

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^./lazer_.{6}$'
```

Comment: Does `ls` only recognize `*` as a wildcard character?

Comment: also accepts `?` and `[ ]`

Comment: It's not `ls` who expands wildcards: it's the shell who does.

Comment: @Lazer What you're experiencing is the difference between [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) and [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Unfortunately, these two grammars share some of the same symbols but they have very different meanings.  In regex, the `.` means any single character but with globs, this is specified by `?`. Shells understand globbing, not regex.

Comment: In Bash, easy way to type `??????`: <Esc> 6 ? or Alt-6 ?

Comment: What does ?????? means? if only ????? doesn't work so just trying to understand why has to have 6 question mark ?

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` you could use a glob like [`?(#cN)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Globbing-Flags) (here the `c` flag requires the previous `?` to match exactly `N` times):

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl -- ?(#c12)
```

if you prefer `ls`:

```
ls -d -- ?(#c12)
```

You can also add qualifiers, e.g. search recursively for regular files with fixed name length:

```
print -rl -- **/?(#c12)(.)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `ksh93`:

```
printf '%s\n' {12}(?)
```

for (non-hidden) files whose name are made of 12 characters.

Or if you prefer regular expressions:

```
printf '%s\n' ~(E)^.{12}$
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [SiegeX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1338/siegex), Shell alone does not understand [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).
If you want a precise filter of your files, you must use regular expressions and hence use a command like `egrep`.

Here, the files you want to list begin with `lazer_` and are followed only by some digits (possibly more or less that 6). I would do it this way:

```
ls | egrep '^lazer_[[:digit:]]*$'
```

This regex works the same as `'^lazer_[0-9]*$'`.

Regular expressions with `egrep` also handles repetition just like in the answer of [wag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3069/wag), if you want to restrict your list to files ending with exactly 6 digits:

```
ls | egrep '^lazer_[[:digit:]]{6}$'
```

Comment: Note that `[:digit:]` is a [POSIX character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `echo` command.

```
echo lazer_??????
```

Note that regular expression handling is done by whatever `shell` the `echo` command is running within.

Comment: The command given in this answer is already described in the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5552).