# How can I select 3 character files in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

I know that a question mark is considered a special character and it has special meaning. Question mark represents a single character that can be any type.

In my practice lesson we have an example :

```
ls ?
```

This will search all files consists of only one character. I want to know how can I search for a specific number of characters. For example: how do I find how many filenames consists of only 3 characters?

Comment: Why don't you answer this in answer portion. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've voted your question up as I'm presuming you are in fact asking this for those instances where you need to match a specific number of characters but where multiple `?`s would be impractical (i.e. 10-20 chars). While 3 `?`s would make sense for simply matching 3 chars this question is relevant for greater numbers.

Comment: [How can I search for a file with fixed name length using ls ?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a start:

```
$ ls | grep -o -w '\w\{3\}'
png
png
log
rdb
png
gfd
gpg
pub
pdf
out
log
gpg
key
txt
txt
the
com
pem
VMs
$
```

The count is

```
$ ls | grep -o -w '\w\{3\}' | wc -l
19
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Even tough this is a bit out of the question, but it works fine! Thanks

Comment: needs a bit more work as it is picking up things like `bloblob.png` because of the three digit extension.

Comment: This answer is WRONG ! It is going to select files with "atleast 3 characters" ! More-over , it is not using Bash, it is using grep. See the comment by @Celada for the correct answer "ls ???"

Comment: @MichaelDurrant , the problem is not that blobblob.png has 3 character extension, the problem is that is has 3 or more letters. Even blobblob.c will get through.

Comment: `ls | grep -x -P  '.{3}' ` ?

Answer (score 6):

The answer of Michael is not correct. If the name has a space you are in trouble:

```
$ ls
aaa bbb ccc ccc a
```

the last item is "ccc a"

```
$ ls | grep -o -w '\w\{3\}'
aaa
bbb
ccc
ccc
```

Celada said the correct answer:

```
$ ls ???
aaa bbb ccc

$ ls ?????
ccc a
```