# It is possible to list all files that have at least 3 letters on its name?

Tags: shell-script

I have to find all files that have a minimum of 3 letters, starting with the letter "l".

I'm using this, but it also gives me the files with less than 3 letters.

> ls | grep "^l"

Is it possible to determine a minimum length? I just know that the char "?" is used to exact lengths.

Comment: Related: [How can I search for a file with fixed name length using ls ?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Bash globs

Don't use regex. Use [globs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) (assuming you are using bash).

```
ls l??*
```

#### Explanation

- `?` stands for a single character.
- `*` stands for zero or more characters.

## Regex

If you really wanted to use regex, you could use

```
ls | grep "^l...*"
```

#### Explanation

- `.` stands for a single character.
- `.*` stands for zero or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using `find` (should work if you aren't using `bash`). This solution will find all files and folders (see below for file-only version) with 3 or more characters that starts with the character 'l' **recursively** (see below for non-recursive) under where you execute it from.

```
find . -regex '.*/l[^/][^/][^/]*'
```

A **non-recursive** version (one that only searches current directory) is as follows.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/l[^/][^/][^/]*'
```

If you do not want to include folders, you can use the following instead.

```
find . -type f -regex '.*/l[^/][^/][^/]*'
```

or (non-recursive)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/l[^/][^/][^/]*'
```