# Copy All Files With Certain Length File Name

Tags: bash, files, filenames, file-copy

In directory `/source` I'd like to copy all files with a file name more than 15 characters to directory `/dest`. Is there a UNIX command to do this?

**EDIT**: Although [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/how-can-i-search-for-a-file-with-fixed-name-length-using-ls) explains how to search for a filename of a certain length, my question also asks how to copy the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I search for a file with fixed name length using ls?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/how-can-i-search-for-a-file-with-fixed-name-length-using-ls)

Comment: I saw that one, but wasn't sure how to adapt it to copying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a pattern with 16-or-more characters and copy those files.

A simple (but not elegant) approach, using 16 `?` characters, each matching any single character:

```
for n in /source/????????????????*;do [ -f "$n" ] && cp "$n" /dest/; done
```

After the 16th `?`, use `*` to match any number of characters.  The pattern might not really match anything, so a test `-f` to ensure it is a file is still needed.

Comment: In bash, you could also use the nullglob shell option to avoid testing if any such file exists.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, there is no command to do specifically that, but you can take advantage of shell glob patterns:

```
cp /source/????????????????* /dest
```

There are **16** question marks preceding the asterisk (you stated that you wanted "more than 15 characters" which means "at least 16").

Below are the caveats to my current answer:

- Depending on your shell's configuration, this may not copy "hidden" files (ie files that starts with dot (`.`))
- This will not copy any directories that are direct children of `/source`. It will simply emit a warning for each directory with a file name length of > 15 characters. If you want to recursively copy everything under `/source` and keep the hierarchy, that answer will be a little more involved.

Answer (score 6):

The `?????????????????????` solution is fine, unless you, like me, cannot count above eight. In such case you can use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.{17,}' -exec cp -t /dest {} +
```

- Notice that `17` should be used to take into account preceding `./`.
- `-regextype posix-egrep` is needed to allow braces `{}`pattern. Default regex type for `find` is *emacs* which doesn't allow that.
- destination should be placed as a first `cp` argument (`-t` option) in order to treat all output from `{} +` as the sources.

Comment: (1) Taking the `./` into consideration, this finds all directories entries that are 15 characters long or longer.  The question says “more than 15 characters”, so you should use `'.{18,}'`.  (2) The question is vague on the precise requirements. As long as you’re using `find` anyway, it would be prudent to include `-type f`.

Answer (score 3):

If referring to a linux system with GNU, Gawk, then below is one solution. Source is `/home/my_folder`, copying to `/dest` for filenames longer than 7 characters assuming no filenames with spaces:

```
ls /home/my_folder/ |awk '{if(length($0)>7){print "cp /home/my_folder/"$0" /dest/"$0";";}}'
```

Which outputs:

```
cp /home/my_folder/orbit-antixcat /dest/orbit-antixcat;
cp /home/my_folder/spacefm-antixcat-569be3dc.tmp /dest/spacefm-antixcat-569be3dc.tmp;
cp /home/my_folder/xsession-modified-date /dest/xsession-modified-date;
```

If that looks OK then pipe through shell to actually copy the files:

```
ls /home/my_folder/ |awk '{if(length($0)>7){print "cp /home/my_folder/"$0" /dest/"$0";";}}'|bash
```

Can add some quotes to accommodate files with spaces in their names:

```
ls /home/my_folder |awk '{if(length($0)>7){print "cp \047/home/my_folder/"$0"\047 \047/dest/"$0"\047;";}}'|bash
```

Example output with quotes:

```
cp '/home/my_folder/kdecache-antixcat' '/dest/kdecache-antixcat';
cp '/home/my_folder/ksocket-antixcat' '/dest/ksocket-antixcat';
```

Can specify the cp binary if it happens to be aliased; perhaps there is a confirmation upon overwrite that you don't want.

```
ls /home/my_folder |awk '{if(length($0)>2){print "/bin/cp \047/home/my_folder/"$0"\047 \047/dest/"$0"\047;";}}'|bash
```

Above can be modified to copy directories if needed; currently they are omitted.

Comment: Thank you for all of the details. The really simple answer worked, as well.

Comment: (1) [Don’t parse the output from `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)  What if there are filenames containing single quotes (a.k.a. apostrophes)?  (2) You don’t need a semicolon (`;`) at the end of a command line.  (3) If you aren’t using bash features (you aren’t), it’s more portable (and possibly more efficient) to specify `sh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: The `ls` parsing is usually something I do interactively but will keep risk in mind and avoid script usage. Concatenating shell commands with the semicolons can be of use for awk output; i.e., executing multiple commands per awk input. Thanks for the good information.